Is it possible to convert reference using anonymous function to arrow function in PHP?
I have
$variables = 1;
// This closure is what I would like to convert.
$some_closure = function (callable $callable) use (&$variables) {
    $callable($variables);
};
// Usage example:
function inc(&$x) {
  $x++;
}
$some_closure('inc');
var_dump($variables);

Which works but I am wondering whether an equivalent shorter arrow function could be written. The RFC points towards a negative but then again, the RFC is from 2019 and since then many wonderful constructs have entered the language.

Short closures would have supported this, but the RFC was declined.

Arrow functions use by-value variable binding. This is roughly equivalent to performing a use($x) for every variable $x used inside the arrow function. A by-value binding means that it is not possible to modify any values from the outer scope.

Does this answer your question? Use variable by reference in arrow function

@shingo respectfully, the PHP documentation is not quite decisive. It can be behind. I should know: I have commit privileges to the docs.
